# Link color different between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

In Firefox, my website displays the word "open" as blue, yet it is some kind of grey in Chrome.

Firefox computed style

```
#content a:link #0645AD 
style.css?ver=1.2 (line 15)
a   #444444  (crossed out)
style.css (line 424)
body    #444444 (colored greY)
style.php?ver=1.2 (line 1)
```

Chrome computed style

```
#content a:hover - #4E8B4E (only item not crossed out)
#content a:link - #0645AD .sticky-title, p.trigger.active a, span.current, .themecolor, a:hover, .tag-links a:hover, .excerpt, .unitedthemes a:hover, .copyright a:hover, .entry-meta a:hover, .entry-meta-single-post a:hover, #footer a:hover, #footer .lambda_widget_twitter a, #footer .lambda_widget_recent_comments a,
#sidebar .lambda_widget_twitter a, #sidebar a:hover, .widget_recent_comments a, .lambda_widget_recent_comments a - #80B600 a - #444444 a:-webkit-any-link - -webkit-link user agent stylesheet body - #444444
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case?

UPDATE: Have a solution now, so the website (http://125.7.123.252/) link is now blue

Comment: @MattF: Blue is the correct style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want but make sure the more specific CSS selector (the one you want) is written below the more general rule you don't want (not only within the same .css document, but if you are using more than one .css file then link to the one you want to take precedence below or "after" other .css stylesheets).

Also it could be an issue with the link already having been visited.

Try this

```
#content a:link, #content a:visited { color:#0645AD }
```

instead of just

```
#content a {color: #0645AD}
```